# Saving strings into ATMega328 with arduino?

Tags: arduino

We need to save `Strings` into `atmega328` chip , for example a user name and password to stay there even after a reset .

I have read that `EEPROM`  is what it need, but than i could see that you can only save `bytes` , so a word would be byte after byte .

I have read this :
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMWriteAnything

But i could see people saying that it has some problem with `Strings` .
So, how can we savee Strings in a reliable way (for mass production)

Answer (score 0):

The EEPROMWriteAnything does in-fact not write everything, it is useful for single instances of objects larger than one byte (not arrays or pointers).

A String class is incompatible due to it using dynamic memory:copying the String object does not copy the 'pointed too' dynamic memory.

What you can do is traverse the String contents.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; ++i ){
  EEPROM.write( address, str[ i ] );
}
```

This is essentially how you'd deal with an array, however the current EEPROM **can** read things larger than one byte, similar to EEPROMWriteAnything using:

```
EEPROM.get( address, object );
EEPROM.put( address, object );
```

There is an update for the EEPROM library which makes dealing with arrays, objects and memory blocks/Strings, but they may not be available till IDE 1.6.6/7. However, these EEPROM helpers only hide the loop you'd otherwise write (it still takes up space).